# Create a component that abstracts logic (from existing code)

Tags: reactjs, scroll, components, refactoring

I create this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { range } from 'lodash'

const DIV_NUMBER = 5

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.divs = []
  }

  handleScroll = divIdx => () => {
    const divRef = this.divs[divIdx]
    const left = divRef.scrollLeft
    const top = divRef.scrollTop
    this.divs.forEach(div => (div.scrollLeft = left))
    this.divs.forEach(div => (div.scrollTop = top))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ border: '1px solid tomato' }}>
        {range(DIV_NUMBER).map(i => {
          return (
            <div
              key={i}
              ref={divElem => (this.divs[i] = divElem)}
              onScroll={this.handleScroll(i)}
              style={{
                width: 300,
                height: 100,
                margin: '2px',
                overflow: 'auto',
                border: '1px solid black',
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  width: 500,
                  height: 400,
                }}
              >
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu
                augue ut lectus. In fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi
                tincidunt ornare. Auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum. Non nisi est sit amet.
                Facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing
                at in tellus integer. Lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper
                viverra. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Porttitor eget
                dolor morbi non. Pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et.
                Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Purus semper eget duis
                at tellus at urna condimentum. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Sit amet
                aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend
                donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis. Tristique senectus et netus et
                malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Enim ut tellus
                elementum sagittis vitae. Urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id
                aliquet. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel
                orci porta. Eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi. Adipiscing commodo
                elit at imperdiet. Facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu lobortis. Volutpat est velit
                egestas dui id ornare arcu odio. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla.
                Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean. Sodales ut
                etiam sit amet nisl. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare. Viverra mauris in aliquam
                sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue.
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It works.
It creates 5 div elements, scrolling one of them, all the div scroll togheter. I use React references to do that.

What I would like to do now is creates a component that abstracts this logic.

I imagine something like that:

```
<ScrollDivs>
  {range(DIV_NUMBER).map(i => {
    return (
      <div
        key={i}
        style={{
          width: 500,
          height: 400,
        }}
      >
        all the text...
      </div>
    )
  })}
</ScrollDivs>
```

So a magic component `ScrollDivs` that deals with logic.
Who uses this component does not have to worry about how it is done, he just needs to wrap the divs that wants to be able to scroll together inside this component.

How can I do? I don't know where to start.

Any help is appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`React.Children.map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) can help you to iterate over `props.children` and [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) can help with passing new props to children:

```
export default class ScrollDivsSync extends React.Component {
  divs = [];

  handleScroll = e => {
    const { scrollTop, scrollLeft } = e.target;
    this.divs.forEach(div => {
      div.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
      div.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    let i = 0;
    const enhancedChildren = React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        onScroll: this.handleScroll,
        ref: divElem => (this.divs[i++] = divElem)
      })
    );

    return enhancedChildren;
  }
}
```

This is a CodeSandbox with [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/r0po2k553n)